# Adding column of buttons for each row in gridcontrol devexpress

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, xtragrid, gridcontrol

How can I add a column of buttons near binded list items of gridcontrol devexpress? Binded list of items to gridcontrol as follows:

```
List<AnObject> lst = new List<AnObject>();
SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (sdr.Read()){
  AnObject object = new AnObject();
  object.ID = Convert.ToInt32(s["ID"]);
  object.Name = s["Name"].ToString();

  lst.Add(object);
}
gridControl1.DataSource = lst;
```

I need to add button at the rightside of each row. Because with click event need to do some work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can assign the [RepositoryItemButtonEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsButtonEdittopic) editor to the specific column in your GridView. Then you can handle the [ButtonClick](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemButtonEdit_ButtonClicktopic) event for button of these editors. To show buttons within separate column you can add a new [unbound column](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/customdocument1477).

Related help-article: 
[Assigning Editors to Columns and Card Fields](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument746)